# How to execute a specific scheduled task in shopware 6?

Tags: plugins, cron, shopware

I want to execute a specific scheduled task. how to do it in shopware 6?

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to execute a scheduled task directly. But you could create a `consoleCommand` which then executes your `ScheduledTaskHandler`. Remember to insert your `ScheduledTaskHandler` dependency into your command command in the `services.xml`.

Comment: Good approach, thank you for saving my day!